# How to refer to an id with special characters in CSS

Tags: css, less, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I’m working on a MediaWiki skin that will be released to the public for anyone to use for free, but there is something that is keeping me from wrapping up the project. Here is the issue.

There is a list that is dynamically generated by MediaWiki (not by the skin, so I have no control over this) and it assigns each `<li>` and id equal to the page name it represents. Now languages other than English have special characters which may show up in these page titles, for example “Página Aleatoria”. For this page I see an id is set replacing the accented character for some code, something that looks like this `<li id="P.C3.A1gina-aleatoria">`.

Now the question is how do I refer to this id in CSS? I have tried `#P.C3.A1gina-aleatoria`, `#página-aleatoria` and `#pagina-aleatoria` but none of those seem to work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  this, you can use "`\`" to escape special characters in [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) like other languages

```
#P\.C3\.A1gina-aleatoria { }
```

Also you can try attribute [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors) like

```
li[id="P.C3.A1gina-aleatoria"] {}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/340ogpwx/)

Comment: Thats it! Thank you! :)

Comment: @GuillermoCarone You can mark it as correct answer if it worked for you..So others can also identify.

Comment: I did, but apparently all my votes won’t show up until I reach a reputation of 15 or more...

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can use a backslash to escape a character which already has meaning in CSS (as ssilas777 demonstrates). The dot is one such character, so it needs escaping:

```
#P\.C3\.A1gina-aleatoria { }
```

If you wanted to use other nonstandard special characters (such as á) in CSS, you can normally just use them unescaped in your code.

```
#Página-aleatoria
```

A full explanation of how to escape other characters in CSS can be found here: 
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes